# Как реализовать подобные адаптивные карточки товаров?

Tags: javascript, html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Карточки продуктов имеют фиксированную ширину и при растяжении окна могут быть больше четырех в строчку. При этом вертикальное выравнивание подписей зависит от их положения в строке. (т.е. если пятый элемент переместится на первую строчку, то он будет выглядеть в точности как четвертый).Высота элементов в **строке** выравнивается по самому высокому в **строке**.(т.е. высота эл-тов первой и второй строки могут быть изначально разными).

Подскажите,пожалуйста, решение этой задачи без использования flex, т.к. нужна поддержка IE9

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p0ag6ya8/30/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.aside {
  width: 25%;
  height: 700px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: red;
}
.main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 700px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: green;
}
.main::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.items {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 0px;
  margin: 35px 0 35px 10px;
}
.items__item {
  width: 175px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.item__img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
.item__img_small {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.item__signature {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside class="aside"></aside>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись<br> к изображению в три строки</div>
      </div>
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img item__img_small">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись<br> в две строки</div>
      </div>
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
      </div>
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
      </div>
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
      </div>
      <div class="items__item">
        <img src="http://credittoolz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/free.png" alt="" class="item__img">
        <div class="item__signature">подпись</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```